# Pause QML Timer?

Tags: javascript, qt, timer, qml

Is there a way to pause a Timer in QML. THe only methods that seem to be available are stop, start, and reset. In my application, I need a way to pause the timer part way through and then start it again from where it left off. However, every time I use the start() method, it resets the timer from the start.

Does anyone know a way to solve this problem or a reasonable alternative? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write simple your own Timer in C++. It's looks like easy way. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html
You don't even need to use low-level times, just wrap QTimer and use, for example, remainingTimeAsDuration() to get current state before stop it.
Other way is write part of logic in js. Just record time of start timer, record time of pause and modify timer duration based on this values when start it again.